# I'm having issues dual-booting eOS on a Macbook!

Tags: boot, dual-boot, macbook, refind

I've been trying to set up a dual boot on my Macbook Pro with a version of elementaryOS and the current version of macOS using rEFInd, but I've been having some issues and I'm not sure where the process went wrong. I'd like to ask you for some help, because maybe you'd know what I'm doing wrong.
I have a 2018 Macbook Pro 13 inch, with macOS 10.14 working, I've installed rEFInd via the installer provided on SourceForge, and burned the .iso onto a pen drive using Etcher (in a Windows 10 PC).
The problem is that when I reboot my Macbook, it's supposed to present me the option of where I want to boot my Macbook from, but it only shows the default macOS drive, and not the pen drive.
I don't know if I was clear enough, so if you need any more information, please let me know.

Comment: Have you tried holding option key while powering on your Mac? You don't need rEFind installed before eOS installation. You may follow this guide.
https://aroman.github.io/elementary-on-a-mac/